# Minimize $\frac{x^2}{x-9} $ given that $x > 9$

Tags: maxima-minima

Its given that $ x > 9 $ and I have to find minima of

$$ y = \frac{x^2}{(x-9) }   $$

I did this using three methods.

Method 1). Let

$$ f(x) = \frac{x^2}{(x-9) }   $$

Using, calculus, we get

$$ f'(x) = \frac{2x}{(x-9)} - \frac{x^2}{(x-9)^2}   $$

Using this, we can find that the critical point is $ x = 18$ and $ f'(x) < 0 $ for $ 9 < x < 18 $ and $ f'(x) > 0 $ for $ x > 18 $. So, using first derivative test, $ f(x) $ has absolute minimum at $x = 18$.  So, we can find that $f(18) = 36 $ is the absolute minimum.

Method 2). Since we have

$$ y = \frac{x^2}{(x-9) }   $$

$$ \Longrightarrow  x^2 - xy +9y = 0 $$

This is a quadratic equation. Now $x > 9$, so it follows that $ y > 0 $.  Now the discriminant of this quadratic equation is

$$ D = y^2 - 36 y $$

Since roots of this quadratic equation are values of $x$ and since $x > 9$, we know that the roots are real and so  we have discriminant $ D \geqslant 0 $, which means that

$$ y ( y-36) \geqslant 0 $$

Since $ y > 0 $, it follows that $ y \geqslant 36 $. So, 36 is the minimum value of $y$.

Method 3.

Now, we have

$$ \frac{(x-9) }{x^2} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{9}{x^2}   $$

$$ \frac{(x-9) }{x^2} = \Big( \frac{1}{9} \Big) \Big( \frac{9}{x} \Big) \Big( 1- \frac{9}{x} \Big) $$

We should note that since $ x > 9$, all quantities above are positive. So, we can now use AM-GM inequality

$$ \frac{9}{x} + \Big( 1- \frac{9}{x} \Big)  \geqslant 2 \bigg[ \frac{9}{x}\Big( 1- \frac{9}{x} \Big) \bigg]^{1/2} $$

$$ 1 \geqslant 6 \bigg [ \frac{1}{x} \Big( 1- \frac{9}{x} \Big) \bigg]^{1/2} $$

$$ \therefore \; \bigg[ \frac{1}{x} - \frac{9}{x^2} \bigg ]  \leqslant \frac{1}{36} $$

$$ \therefore \; \frac{(x-9) }{x^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{36} $$

$$ \therefore \; \frac{x^2}{x-9} \geqslant 36 $$

So, the minimum value is $36$

Are these good approaches ?

Comment: The last approach only proves that the minimum is at least $36.$ To get that there is a value when equal, you need to know there is an $x$ such that $\frac9x=1-\frac9x.$

Comment: Yes Thomas, I forgot that part.  Slava Ukraini :)

Comment: FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%7D%7Bx-9%7D%24&p=1), there's [Minimum Value of $\frac{x^2}{x-9}$ using AM-GM inequality](/q/1599117), [AM - GM inequality](/q/2072465) and [Normal AM-GM inequality](/q/2454549), plus the AoPS threads [AM-GM Minimization](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1733587p11246513) and [AM - GM?](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1359841p7448674).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the methods stated by you are quite good.(I personaly would have preferred the discrimant one as it is a comparitively shorter method).

Also,I would like to state another method which is similar(but simpler)to your last method:

$\frac{x^2}{(x-9) }=\frac{x^2-81+81}{(x-9) }=18+(x-9) +\frac{81}{(x-9) }$

Following which, AM-GM can be applied as $x>9$.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another method:
$$ \frac{x^2}{x-9}=\frac{(x-18)^2+36x-18^2}{x-9}
=36+\frac{(x-18)^2}{x-9}\ge 36$$
with equality iff $x=18$.